# Using a for loop index in .loc to access a rolling slice of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, slice

I want to create rolling slices of a master dataframe. I'm trying to measure the difference in outcomes over rolling periods. The master dataframe has 120 years of data and I want to create rolling slices of 10 years of a column(s), i.e slice one goes from year 1 to 10, slice 2 goes from year 2 to 11, etc...

I'm trying to create one slice dataframe that contains all the slices, 12 rolling 10 year periods in my example.

I'm trying to do it in a for loop like this:

```
length_of_slice = 10
slice_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(length_of_slice)) 
   
for i in range(0, len(slice_df)):

       slice_df['Data'+ str(i)] = master_df.loc[i:(i+9)]['Data'].to_list()
```

So, the first run through this should give me row 0 to 9 of master _df in the 10 rows of slice_df. The second time through the loop should give me row 1 to 10 of master_df in the 10 rows of slice_df.

I keep getting a ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.
Can I use the index of a for loop in .loc like this? Is there a better approach to this?

If I do the steps in sequential order outside a for loop it works.

```
slice_df['Data1'] = master_df.loc[0:9]['Data'].to_list()
slice_df['Data2'] = master_df.loc[1:10]['Data'].to_list()
...
```

So, it's something I'm doing in the for loop.

Comment: Are you aware of the [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) method?

Comment: I am. I use it all the time. But it doesn't help me in this case. I want a different 'view' of the data for many reasons, not just performing some calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to iterate over the output of [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html#pandas-dataframe-rolling).

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

n = 10
master_df = pd.DataFrame({"Data": np.random.randint(0, 99, size=20)})
slice_df = pd.DataFrame([list(i) for i in master_df["Data"].rolling(n)]).dropna().T

slice_df.columns = [f"Data{i}" for i, _ in enumerate(slice_df, start=1)]
```

will give you e.g.

```py
   Data1  Data2  Data3  Data4  Data5  Data6  Data7  Data8  Data9  Data10  Data11
0   31.0   84.0   85.0    7.0   71.0   58.0   88.0   83.0   17.0    98.0    57.0
1   84.0   85.0    7.0   71.0   58.0   88.0   83.0   17.0   98.0    57.0    23.0
2   85.0    7.0   71.0   58.0   88.0   83.0   17.0   98.0   57.0    23.0    74.0
3    7.0   71.0   58.0   88.0   83.0   17.0   98.0   57.0   23.0    74.0    75.0
4   71.0   58.0   88.0   83.0   17.0   98.0   57.0   23.0   74.0    75.0    76.0
5   58.0   88.0   83.0   17.0   98.0   57.0   23.0   74.0   75.0    76.0    30.0
6   88.0   83.0   17.0   98.0   57.0   23.0   74.0   75.0   76.0    30.0    93.0
7   83.0   17.0   98.0   57.0   23.0   74.0   75.0   76.0   30.0    93.0    96.0
8   17.0   98.0   57.0   23.0   74.0   75.0   76.0   30.0   93.0    96.0    71.0
9   98.0   57.0   23.0   74.0   75.0   76.0   30.0   93.0   96.0    71.0    58.0
```